# Glew Linking Issue

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

When i try to link dynamically against glew, the linker will throw errors like `undefined reference: __imp___glewGenVertexArrays`. The basic meaning is clear - the linker can't find any address to link the function calls against.

What bothers me is that i used the normal glew.h header and linked against glew32 (not glew32s - i'll come to that later on). Not defining `#define GLEW_STATIC`, Glew should link dynamically out of the box. But the undefined error indicates that somehow it is trying to link statically against them. So i fixed it by linking against `glew32s` and added `#define GLEW_STATIC` before `#include "GL/glew.h"`

But this is in my opinion just a workarround - i want to know why glew assumes static linking, when not asked to. Especially why it even doesn't work when you just link against glew32s by not defining `GLEW_STATIC`

**Update**
I'm using gcc 5.1.0 mingw64

Full error when linking against `glew32` having `GLEW_STATIC` NOT defined:

```
src\SDLWrapper\CoreWindowSDL.o: In function `CoreWindow_SDL::enterMain()':
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:61: undefined reference to `__imp___GLEW_VERSION_4_5'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:68: undefined reference to `__imp___glewGenVertexArrays'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:69: undefined reference to `__imp___glewBindVertexArray'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:74: undefined reference to `__imp___glewGenBuffers'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:76: undefined reference to `__imp___glewBindBuffer'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:77: undefined reference to `__imp___glewBufferData'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:109: undefined reference to `__imp___glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:110: undefined reference to `__imp___glewBindBuffer'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:111: undefined reference to `__imp___glewVertexAttribPointer'
D:\workspace\Engine\Debug/../src/SDLWrapper/CoreWindowSDL.cpp:114: undefined reference to `__imp___glewDisableVertexAttribArray'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The question is, these functions should be loaded at runtime, why is gcc/glew trying to link against them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a mingw and not a glew issue. I don't know the solution but maybe the reimp http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs tool might help.

Comment: updated to gcc 5.2.0, still no improvement

Comment: the linker expects symbols prefixed with __imp_ but I suppose they are exported without the __imp_ prefix. With the reimp tool and the right options you should be able to create a *.a library from the lib file that can be used with mingw

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem using VS2015 and GLEW 1.13.0 for both x86 and x64 and everything works fine. No linker errors.

> Glew should link dynamically out of the box. But the undefined error
>   indicates that somehow it is trying to link statically against them.

You understand this wrong. It links statically to the dll import library but when your programm is executed it will dynamically link the glew.dll. Linking to the glew32.lib file which is the dll import library will resolve the references to the symbols at link time. When you start your compiled program the dll will then be linked dynamically.

When you link the the static library no dll will be required afterwards.

Comment: Yeah i know, it is common practice to have an static helper library which deals with the import of the dll. And that the dll is not required when linking the main library static is also clear. Updating my question